# Linux (Centos) and Nginx permissions on another disk

Tags: linux, nginx

I have an issue with nginx and linux (centos).
Nginx use the disk as a temp buffer for big POST request.
By default, the cache is located here:

```
/var/cache/nginx/client_temp/ (drwx------.  2 nginx root)
```

It works but the disk is very small. When you try to upload a big file (or multiple files at the same time), the disk is full.

So we add a new disk (`/data`) and we change the `client_body_temp_path` parameters to the new disk `/data/tmp`.
When we try to upload something, we have a permission error:

```
nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/data/tmp" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I change permission (`chmod`/`chown`) on this directory with:

- same as the default directory rights: `drwx------. 2 nginx root`
- full access: `drwxrwxrwx. 2 nginx nginx`

But this does not works (same error).
If I log as the nginx user in a terminal, I can access/create files inside this directory. The error is only inside nginx server.

Something strange:
If the directory is located on the partition:

```
 /var/... => permission ok
 /tmp/... => permission ok
 /data/... => permission not ok
```

var and tmp are on the same physical disk (but different partition). data is another disk.

Am I suppose to give authorization access to user 'nginx' for a specific drive/disk in Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this problem is caused by SELinux, which uses a different way to manage privileges. plz try to turn off selinux temporarily and try it again

```
setenforce 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had nearly exactly the same problem, and yes it was caused by SELinux.

Here's what worked for me:

```
chcon -v -R --type=httpd_sys_content_t <www-root>
```

This recursively modifies the file "label" in the target directory to allow nginx ("context" httpd_t) to access it.

My reference for figuring it out: [NGINX: SELinux Changes when Upgrading to RHEL 6.6 / CentOS 6.6](http://nginx.com/blog/nginx-se-linux-changes-upgrading-rhel-6-6/)

Answer (score 0):

Nginx can access /var and /tmp because SELinux treats them as well-known locations and grant permission by default.  For the other location you have to grant permission explicitly:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_rw_t /data/tmp
```

And remember to reload nginx to take effect:

```
systemctl reload nginx.service
```