# Linux (Ubuntu) and Nginx permissions on another disk when i use client_body_temp_path

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, permission-denied, selinux, apparmor

I upload big size(5-100GB) single file over nginx. And Nginx save it temporarily in a path. I need to change the temporarily path to another disk's path. My backend application moves the file to in the disk. But the copy-paste is too slow and I got timeout error.

the disk is mounted on /etc/fstab

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/24c495a2-1fb1-46a7-8ae1-d425f5b67d4a /media/cesium auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Here is my configfile

```
server {
    listen 14000;
    server_name _;
    client_max_body_size 100G;  
    
    client_body_temp_path /media/cesium/nginx_tmp;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:13001;
    }
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:13002/api/;
    }

}
```

Here is what get on the nginx error log file `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

```
2021/07/08 12:30:00 [crit] 11595#11595: *159 open() "/media/cesium/nginx_tmp/0000000002" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.20.180, server: _, request: "POST /api/v1/terrain/5/uploadfile HTTP/1.0", host: "192.168.20.201:14000", referrer: ...
```

Here is what I tried to solve this then I failed.

- I changed the nginx.service user to root.
- I changed the whole disk's permissions to 777
- My question looks duplicated with [Linux (Centos) and Nginx permissions on another disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273035/linux-centos-and-nginx-permissions-on-another-disk) but not. I tried to install selinux on ubuntu. I could not boot with selinux again. I disabled selinux on ubuntu.

Is this related with apparmor ?

Answer (score 1):

I just remount the disk. And there is no problem left.

`sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb1 /media/cesium`